# Customizing model name in ActiveAdmin filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can I customise model name in ActiveAdmin filter here? [image]

This way doesn't work:

```
activerecord:
  models:
    category:
      one: "категория"
      other: 'категории'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter :title, :label => "Change me"
filter :description, :label => "Change Me"
filter :user, :label => "Change Me"
```

[image]

You could also use `I18n.t` if you wanted to

```
    filter :title, :label => (I18n.t "some.key.here")
```

Comment: `I18n.t "some.key.here"` really wont work on loading.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin uses metasearh ,so next rule works for me. (destination - parent model, rateplan - nested model)
Example:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      destination:
       rateplan: "RATEPLAN LOCALIZED NAME"
```

more info: https://github.com/ernie/meta_search#localization

UPD.

One more soulution is using  fortastic rules for internalizaton

```
en:
  formtastic:
    labels:
      rateplan: "RATEPLAN LOCAIZED"
```

more info: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#internationalization-i18n

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin uses [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) to render filter as like the form fields. So you can customize you filters as you like as the formtastic'c customization options are really handy. For example. to change filters label: just use `label: 'YOUR CUSTOM LABEL'` option in filter method. You can use translations there as well